# Base64 Image not show react-native

Tags: react-native, base64

I have a react-native project.

When i want put user profile image I send a API request like that

```
userImageGet(imdl_id) {
API.postValue('/api/UserImage/?imdl_id='+imdl_id,null)      
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(r.data); // 
      this.setState({userImagebs64:r.data}); // here's user base64 string
    })
}
```

like that ( I crushed image for special information but it's work on web browser) it's too long

```
data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIy
```

and I have a `userRenderImage`  function like that

```
userRenderImage() {
    let userImage = null;
    if (this.state.userImagebs64) {
      // here I got base64 format
      userImage = (
        <Image
           style={styles.userImage}
          source={{ uri: this.state.userImagebs64}}
        />
      );
    }
    return userImage;
}
```

Image style

```
userImage: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 50,
    padding: 5
}
```

it's render method but I don't see anything any advice is welcome

Comment: How does `styles.userImage` look like?

Comment: I added in question

Comment: can you plz try `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==` this image, if that's works might be your base64 image is corrupted

Comment: That's a huge border radius which is probably overriding your image rendering.  Try setting it to 5

Comment: @ShaileshRathod I know I write it why corrupted but it's too long

Comment: @MikeM I delete all style just edit height and width 100 still same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worked for me.

I define a new varible my code lines top like that

```
let UserImage = "";
```

then `API` response I change `UserImage` value like this.

```
userImageGet(imdl_id) {
API.postValue('/api/UserImage/?imdl_id='+imdl_id,null)      
.then((r) => {
  console.log(r.data); // 
  UserImage = r.data;
  this.setState({userImagebs64:r.data}); // here's user base64 string
})
```

}

I use `<Image>`

```
 <Image
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: UserImage}}
    />
```

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me like a charm

```
<Image style={styles.imgstyle} source={{uri: "data:image/png;base64,"+this.state.upic}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

With the base64 string generated chk here if t is a valid string. https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder.

Second pass the base 64 as a post body parameter instead of URL params.

Third check the response of the api if it returns the valid base64 string again which can be decoded to an image using the web link shared above.

If all this works, there shouldn't be a problem in rendering it in the app as code seems to be ok.

Answer (score -1):

here is my Example.i know its late but maybe helpfull for others

```
 <Image
                                style={{
                                    width: 51,
                                    height: 51,
                                    resizeMode: 'contain'
                                }}
                                source={{uri: "data:image/png;base64,"+this.state.yourImageLink}}
                            />
```

in source you must write `uri: "data:image/png;base64`